# Array vacio en Laravel PHP

Tags: php, sql, laravel, array, bucle-for

Tengo las siguientes consultas dentro de un par de ciclos for por cuestiones de obtener datos

El problema es que la segunda consulta es decir la que esta dentro del segundo for me devuelve arrays vacíos

```
  for($i=0; $i <$max; $i++) {

        $iduser=$array[$i]->iduser;

        $datos[]=DB::select( "SELECT T1.IDUSER as IDUSER, ROUND(SUM(hor),1,0) as  total,T1.MONO,T1.LINEITEM,T1.PN,T1.OPNSEQ
        from
        (SELECT IDUSER,TIEMPO,(TIEMPO/60) as hor,MONO,LINEITEM,PN,OPNSEQ
        FROM [dbo].[datos]
            where  date between '{$date}' and '{$date2}' and IDUSER=$iduser) as T1
        Group by IDUSER,T1.MONO,T1.LINEITEM,T1.PN,T1.OPNSEQ");

        $a=count($datos[$i]);

        for ($z=0; $z <$a ; $z++) {

            $MONO=$datos[$i][$z]->MONO;
            $LINEITEM=$datos[$i][$z]->LINEITEM;
            $PN=$datos[$i][$z]->PN;
            $OPNSEQ=$datos[$i][$z]->OPNSEQ;
            $IDUSER=$datos[$i][$z]->IDUSER;

            $variable[]=DB::Select("SELECT A.OPN as OPN,C.VALOR as VALOR
                FROM clasificacion C
                LEFT JOIN answers A ON C.IDCLASIFICACION=A.IDCLASIFICACION
                LEFT JOIN wpl W ON A.OPN=W.OPN
                RIGHT JOIN datos D ON D.OPNSEQ=W.OPNSEQ
                WHERE  W.MONO=$MONO and W.LINEITEM=$LINEITEM and W.PN='$PN' and W.OPNSEQ=$OPNSEQ and D.IDUSER=$IDUSER
                Group by A.OPN,C.VALOR");
        }
```

Imprimo la una conprovacion dd()  y obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme llevo ya varios días con esto.

Comment: Una de tus condiciones esta haciendo que la consulta te la devuelva vacia, pienso en porque no pruebas a verificar los datos anteriores uno por uno, porque con uno que que no coincida, te devolvera vacio.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer consultas con eloquent, son muy faciles de hacer y de entender, tu error esta en `Group by IDUSER,T1.MONO,T1.LINEITEM,T1.PN,T1.OPNSEQ` revisa eso con su select inicial

Comment: @leoncenteno acabo de hacer lo que me dijiste de verificar las datos y están correctos es decir a la consulta llegan bien, peor siguen sin mantener un valor dentro

Comment: @Shassain ya agregue lo que me faltaba en mi "Group by" y tampoco ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo pondría el sql en una variable y luego lo imprimiria para ver si esta toda bien con el sql resultante y luego lo probaria directamente en mysql a ver que te devuelve

```
$sql= "SELECT A.OPN as OPN,C.VALOR as VALOR
            FROM clasificacion C
            LEFT JOIN answers A ON C.IDCLASIFICACION=A.IDCLASIFICACION
            LEFT JOIN wpl W ON A.OPN=W.OPN
            RIGHT JOIN datos D ON D.OPNSEQ=W.OPNSEQ
            WHERE  W.MONO=$MONO and W.LINEITEM=$LINEITEM and W.PN='$PN' 
              and W.OPNSEQ=$OPNSEQ and D.IDUSER=$IDUSER
            Group by A.OPN,C.VALOR";
print $sql;
//$variable[]=DB::Select($sql);
```

Comment: Hola @imaginabit , no habia entendido bien tu respuesta y ya lo hice pero sigo teniendo el array vacio, con el print $sql; pude ver que si todo va bien con la consulta la puse en SQL y si me devuelve lo que busco. El problema es en Codigo que me sigue mandando arrays vacíos